# Compare date and timestamp with timezone

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement, timestamp

I am using JavaScript and I have a date and a timestamp wit time zone and I would like to see if they are equal in a if statement. How do you compare these two formats to see if they are equal.

> Date: 2018-12-25T06:00:00+01:00
>   Timestamp with timezone: 2018-12-25T11:00:00.000Z

```
var date = Date
var timestamp = Timestamp with timezone
if(date == timestamp){
  console.log("Are the same")
}
```

Comment: Your timestamp actually has a timezone — the `Z` is telling you it's UTC.

Comment: Yes you are correct I will edit it thank you.

Comment: They’re both timestamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass both to `new Date` and cast to number using `Date#getTime()` or `+` operator then do an equality check.

The `Z` is for "Zulu" which is UTC time

```js
const d1 = '2018-12-25T06:00:00+01:00', d2 = '2018-12-25T05:00:00.000Z';

console.log(+new Date(d1) === +new Date(d2))
```